# Passing XHTML mimeType to Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, xhtml, mime-types

I need to load a local XHTML file with .html extension with the correct mimetype "application/xhtml+xml" in a Android WebView control. Being that the WebView has to load a Javascript interface I have to call

```
webView.loadData("","text/html",null)
```

first, and then I call

```
webView.loadUrl(localUrlString)
```

I have to pass the right mimeType because of some wrong behaviour of certain JS functions when self-closing tags are encountered but

```
webView.loadData("", "application/xhtml+xml", null);
```

just causes the WebView to display an error message: "This XML file does not appear to have a style associated with it. The document tree is shown below".

How can achieve my goal?

Comment: You're on the right track, but that error means it's not a valid XHTML file. What happens if you change the extension to `.xhtml` and then load it in an ordinary browser? I'll bet it will give the same error. One thing that comes to mind is a missing or incorrect `xmlns` attribute in the `<html>` start tag.

Comment: @Mr Lister The local .html file is an ePub chapter so it should already have the right mimetype and attributes. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, can you tell me what the start tag for the html looks like?

Comment: @Mr Lister, <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"   and  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

Comment: That didn't come out very well, but I think what you typed was OK. Then I don't know what goes wrong (the error you get is when you don't have that). Sorry!